# How to fetch code (open status) from Gerrit?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

Right now I'm using **Gerrit change Id** to fetch specific change code from **Gerrit's open status** via command line.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: The [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html). Unclear, what's your point. Please be more verbose.

Comment: currently I'm fetching changes by using gerrit change Id.because my changes are not yet verified. Changes are still in open status.

Comment: If my answer isn't what you wanted, again, please be more verbose. It's unclear to me, what you want.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? I removed the _jenkins_ tag from your question, as I see no relation. Maybe this would help a lot to solve your problem instead of very vague describing the problem. To be honest, I won't respond any further, if you next response isn't clear enough. Please learn to write better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the code of proposed changes in Gerrit using the *Download* dropdown on the upper right side:

[image: Download links]

Comment: I need command line option. I don't want to fetch manually. thanks

Comment: Then have a look at the schema, how these links are built. You can then derive the URL based on the knowledge about the change ID and patch set number.